# Github actions for getting file diff between current opened PR request and main branch

Tags: git, github, github-actions, pull-request, git-diff

I'm trying to create a github actions workflow for tracking and approving workflow for a Pull request related to modifications of specific file test.json.
The workflow will be Triggered once a PR request is opened and the requirement is to capture the entries added / deleted by comparing the diff between PR branch opened and main branch.
I need to grep and check for specific String in the diff. Eg new user entry added to the json file and take the next action.

test.json :-

```
{
    "users": {
        "test01": {
            "username": "test01",
            "email": "test01@gmailcom",
            "department": "it",
            "access_in_ns": {"test/test1":"admin","test/test2":"admin","rdp/rdp/nonprod":"user"}
        },
    }
}
```

The main challenge i'm facing is getting the file modifications before the PR is merged to main branch [ie. once PR is opened] .

I don't want to get the modified file name but changes to the specific file test.json introduced in the PR request.

Here is the code i have written till now however,it doesn't give the diff between the newly opened PR request the last commit to main branch.

```
name: Test workflow

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
    types: [opened]
    paths:
      - 'test.json'

jobs:
  Job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      PR_AUTHOR_GITHUB_ID: ${{ github.event.pull_request.user.login }}
    steps:
      - name: Find Github id of PR AUTHOR
        run: |
          echo "PR author: ${PR_AUTHOR_GITHUB_ID}"
      - name: Checkout pull request HEAD
        id: checkout_pr_head
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: print-diff
        shell: bash
        run: |
          git fetch origin main
          git diff origin/main..HEAD > mydiff
          echo "mydiff = "
          cat mydiff
```

Comment: Are your sure. I've just run your workflow against my repository and it shows the diff for my file changed in the PR:
```
diff --git a/test.yaml b/test.yaml
index b723c62..593bf0a 100644
--- a/test.yaml
+++ b/test.yaml
@@ -27,20 +27,20 @@ body:
...
 ```